# findAll by multiple conditions

Tags: yii

I have 4 tables:

- content
- relation
- subject
- group

content:

```
id(int)
title(varchar)
text(text)
```

subject:

```
id(int)
title(varchar)
prent_id(int)
```

group:

```
id(int)
title(varchar)
```

relation:

```
id(int)
content_id(int)
group_id(int)
subject_id(int)
```

**relation** to **content** is **many to many**.

**group** to **content** is **many to many**.

**subject** to **content** is **many to many**.

Content may belong to several subjects or several groups.

I want to execute a query somewhat like this:

```
select * from relation where group_id = 1,3 and subject_id = 1,4,6,7
```

Comment: Please give a further explanation of your db structure and include the code for your models.

Comment: "find all content in 2 group and 3 subject" - what exactly do you mean by that? can you reword that? do you mean something like group with id=2, and subject id=3?

Comment: Relation table: `id`, `content_id`, `group_id` and `subject_id`. Maybe `Tag` is better than `subject`

Comment: @bool.dev No dude, sorry. group_id = 2 and 3 - subject_id = 4 and 5 and 7 (tag like)

Comment: if you can add the sql, that you want to be executed, question will be clear.

Comment: @bool.dev has been added.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`findAllByAttributes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail):

```
$relation_models = Relation::model()->findAllByAttributes(array(
        'group_id'=>array('2','3'),
        'subject_id'=>array('4','5','7')
    )
);
```

That will give you something like (actual query may contain alias):

```
select * from relation where group_id IN (1,3) and subject_id IN (1,4,6,7)
```

---

However if you want : `where group_id IN (1,3) OR subject_id IN (1,4,6,7)` (i.e OR instead of AND) then you will have to use [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = 'group_id IN (1,3) OR subject_id IN (1,4,6,7)'
$relation_models = Relation::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

You could also use `addInCondition` :

```
$criteria->addInCondition('group_id', array('1','2'), 'OR');
$criteria->addInCondition('subject_id', array('1','4','6','7'), 'OR');
$relation_models = Relation::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

---

Remember to bind parameters incase you are taking input from user, though. Something like this:

```
$criteria->condition = 'group_id IN (:gid1, :gid2) OR subject_id IN (:sid1, :sid2, :sid3, :sid4)';     
$criteria->params = array(':gid1'=>$xyz,':gid2'=>'2',':sid1'=>$uvw,':sid2'=>$abc,':sid3'=>'6',':sid4'=>'7');
$relation_models = Relation::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: I have added a few more details to the answer, to make it more complete, do check them out. I have also edited your question to make it a little more generic, for easy searching.

Comment: How will you approach if 
`(1,4,6,7)'` is available in array ? Is there any specific query builder in yii?
i.e. instead of 1,4,6,7 we have these elements in an array().

Comment: @Tauseef not sure what you are asking, can you explain a bit more? maybe add some code sample too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use with()

the orginal relation names will be in your relation model if you select Build Relations option on gii when you were creating model.

```
    $relation_models = Relation::model()->with('contents','groups','subjects')->findAllByAttributes(array(
        'group_id'=>array('2','3'),
        'subject_id'=>array('4','5','7')
    ));
```